# Update theme configuration

Tags: theming, 8

I want to update my theme settings. So that i can use it in one of my templates. ( page.html.twig )

Do i need to uninstall my theme every time when i need a new setting?

There must be a way to update my settings so that i can use it right away.

My question : How to import my theme settings immediately?

My settings/configuration are in the config/install directory

Here is an example :

```
header_title_enabled: true
header_slogan_enabled: true
```

I want to use this settings in an template like so :

```
{{ header_title_enabled }}
{{ dump(header_title_enabled) }}

{% include directory ~ '/partials/header.html.twig' %}

{{ page.content }}

{% include directory ~ '/partials/footer.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache? The button is on Administration > Configuration > Development > Performance.

Comment: @Neograph734 Yes i cleared the cache. Setting/Config is not found, the dump says : NULL

Comment: Everything in config->install directory goes to db when you install a module/theme (yes, you need reinstall every time or change in db directly). Most of twig variables comes from `preprocess` function, so, to use something from config, you must load it and pass to a variable in a `preprocess` function and use in your twig file (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8). There is another way, but involve create an Entity.